# Swift 3 Filter decimal only in TextField

Tags: ios, swift

I need a filter only decimal in TextField.

I have this code:

```
Func textField (_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
         Let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
         Let characterSet = CharacterSet (charactersIn: string)
         Return allowedCharacters.isSuperset (of: characterSet)
     }
```

It works correctly - ie it accepts only numbers (ie: 1, 2, 5, 10, 400 etc).
I need to still accept eg 1.25, 4.65, 23.32 (decimal numbers).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line of code

```
Let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
```

Into

```
let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "1234567890.")
```

Basically, the idea is that you need to create you own set of accepted characters, and then do the validation

To further simplify your code, try this

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string == "" {return true}
    return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "1234567890.")) == nil ? false : true
}
```

Comment: Don't post code in comments. It's unreadable. Edit your question and paste the code at the bottom under a `##Here is my new code` banner.

Comment: @user1177107 Updated. replace your function with mine

Comment: Thank you, now the numbers work with a comma. The button has been disabled since deleting text. Can you restore it? :)

Comment: @user1177107 I'm not quite sure about your question. If it's not related to this one, please give me a thumb up here and posy another question. Thank you :)

Comment: This is the same problem. At the moment the number of double type is already entered :) Thank you very much for the help :) The problem is to delete the typed text in this TextField. In the earlier backspace function it was possible to delete the text. It does not work right now :)

Comment: @user1177107 Sure. Don't forget to mark it as correct answer and vote it up :)